# After building rviz from source, how to tell rviz plugin to use this different rviz location?

Tags: ros-noetic, rviz-plugins

I use Ubuntu 20.04 and ROS Noetic. I have built rviz from source (with newer Ogre) and it is located in a separate workspace. Rviz works as expected but one needed plugin does not load any more after building rviz. How to tell rviz plugin (jsk_rviz_plugin/Plotter2D) that it should now look for the custom built rviz in a different location? Or what is a good practice for this?

What I have tried:
I have sourced my new rviz workspace and tried to understand the error. Based on the error message the problem is that base class type rviz::Display does not exist. So I concluded that the plugin location configuration broke after I built rviz in a different workspace.
I then read common plugin load issues and checked the plugin_description.xml, but only in the rviz directory (the jsk plugin is not described there). I learned that each plugin has a separate directory and the related plugin_description.xml is inside this directory. The jsk_rviz_plugins directory is not present in the new rviz workspace. But I did not find where such config is described or could be changed so that the jsk plugin comes along into the new workspace. I would like to understand how it got lost.

EDIT:

I now know the reason why jsk rviz plugins got lost (apt removed it because I built rviz with newer Ogre and older Ogre versions could not co-exist apparently). But the question in the headline remains. I have rviz built from source with newer ogre and I would like to tell jsk_rviz_plugin to use default ros install rviz (in /opt/ros/noetic...). Is it even possible?